# how to return Action<bool> inside method?

Tags: c#, callback, return, action

I have the following code in my class:

```
private static void SetUserMeta(string pUserToken, string pMetaKey, string pMetaValue, Action<bool> callback)
{
    BuddyClient client = CreateBuddy();
    bool rValue = false;

    client.LoginAsync((user, state) =>
    {
        if (state.Exception != null)
        {
            rValue = false;
        }
        else
        {
           client.Metadata.SetAsync((result, resultState) =>
            {
                if (resultState.Exception != null)
                {
                    rValue = false;
                }
                else
                { 
                   rValue = true;
                } 
            }, key: pMetaKey, value: pMetaValue);
        }

        callback(rValue);
    }, token: pUserToken);
 }
```

and I want to get `rValue` and return it from my other method which is the following

```
public static void SetBuddyData(string pUserToken, BuddyData pMetaValue, Action<bool> callback)
{
    //my problem is here and I don't know how to get and return data from SetUserMeta
    return SetUserMeta(pUserToken, "SavedGameData", pMetaValue.Serialize());
}
```

And also I want to call this return value from my application. These codes are in my library. How can I do it?

Comment: Regardess of what the `SetUserMeta` signature is, this will cause an error.  Your `SetBuddyData` is void and needs to match `SetUserMeta`

Comment: When I change void to bool I can't handle callback. How can I construct the system to get return value which comes async from the buddy system?

Comment: Note that you pass `pMetaValue.Serialize()` as a delegate, which seems like an error to me. Check your contents of a `SetBuddyData` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass callback to `SetUserMeta` like

```
public static void SetBuddyData(string pUserToken, BuddyData pMetaValue, Action<bool> callback)
{
    SetUserMeta(pUserToken, "SavedGameData", callback);
}
```

And call `SetBuddyData` like this

```
SetBuddyData("my user token", myBundle, isLoggedIn => HandleUserLogin(isLoggedIn));
```

Where at `HandleUserLogin` you will process bool callback data, returned at `callback(rValue);` in `SetUserMeta` method. It's body example is shown 
next

```
public static void HandleUserLogin(bool isLogged)
{
   Console.WriteLine("user is {0} logged in", isLogged ? "" : "not");
}
```

You also can take advantage of method group syntax and call `SetBuddyData` method like:

```
SetBuddyData("my user token", myBundle, HandleUserLogin);
```